# What is the actual time complexity of any loop say a for loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

When we have to calculate the complexity of a loop say a FOR loop (which say needs to run for n times), should we also count the iteration when the FOR loop's condition fails and it breaks?

Here's an example:

`i` and `n` are positive integers

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   //some code. All are constant expressions and there are no break statements.
}
```

Now the inner code will run for 0 to n-1 times which is n times. When i = n, loop breaks but this happens only after the for loop condition is checked. Should this last check be counted for time complexity because if it is counted then FOR loop will actually be running for n+1 times? I'm not sure if I am making sense here. I guess it should be counted. Still I need some clear answer here. Please suggest!

Comment: Anyway, `O(n + 1)` is `O(n)`, just like for any given `g < f`, `O(f + g) = O(f)` since the computational complexity is **asymptotical.**

Comment: Yes I understand that but to be precise, if I have to know how many iterations will be counted for time complexity then what is this count?

Comment: That does not make sense - there's a reason complexity is defined as it's defined.

Comment: It's not about the number of iterations. It's about how `n` affects the number of iterations. In this case it's linear, which is `O(n)`. Imagine it like this: If you plot the number of iterations for different `n`, will it be a straight line? `n/100` is also linear and `O(n)`, for example.

Comment: Yes @Keyser, I understand that. May be I am not clear in my question here. I know that for a time complexity (read Big-O), constants are eliminated since they do not have dependency on N (input size). So O(N+1) = O(N), O(2N) = O(N) and so on. All I am saying is how many iterations of the aforementioned FOR loop will be taken for complexity, **n** or **n+1** although they are going to fetch me the same answer.

Comment: @Praveen Then the answer is no, the last check will not be counted. The relevant part is the contents of the loop (and how many times it's executed), not the comparisons. In general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to be exact, introduce some constants. Let `a` be the time to check the loop condition once and `b` the time to run all the commands in the loop. The loop will run in a total time of:

```
a(n+1) + bn = (a+b)n + a
```

You seldom need to be this exact though, for the reasons explained by other answers. When `n` is much larger than `a` the time to do `a` once is not relevant to the big picture. That's why we **drop all lower-order terms and constants** and say that:

```
(a+b)n + a ∈ Θ(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

The main point of working out the computational complexity of a function is to determine whether that function will scale well as *n* increases, not how many times it will run for a particular value of *n*. For example, your loop may run perfectly fast when *n* is 1, but if n is suddenly 1000, will it run in (approximately) 1000x the original time, or are you looking a much higher factor?

A for loop like the one you gave will always run - worst case - *n* times. Whether *n* is 100 or 10^30, the loop will involve *n* iterations. An extra comparison on that loop is irrelevant considering the bigger picture; if you're dealing with 10^30 iterations then a single extra iteration is not going to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

As mention, time complexity is asymptotic - this mean that if you have a loop from 1 to n
it doesn't matter how many operation you do in the loop - as long as they are final, the complexity will be `O(n)` , since `O(10000n) = O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

time complexities are not measured considering constants.. As MZF said.. O(an+c)=O(n) where 'a' and 'c' are constants. But if there is one more loop within that for loop, then time complexity will be O(a(n^2) +c) and so on...